# Is there a buffered/high impedance voltage monitoring circuit with voltage limiting?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, bjt, buffer

I have a 10 mA circuit that I would like to monitor. I'm only interested in the values between 0 V and 3.3 V and only have a 3.3 V supply. But the circuit can end up as high as 18 V. I cannot load the original circuit very much. Can anyone suggest what to use?

I've looked at op-amps but the ones I've seen with over-voltage protection seem to use diodes to drop the voltage back down, which seems like it would load the circuit.

I've looked at the LM321 as the input voltage can go up to 32 V. It seems like it might work but it looks like it can't go anywhere near the rails for output.

I've considered a BJT common collector but when the input goes higher than the source, current flows from base to collector. I've tried adding another NPN with the base tied to source. While that prevents the current flow, it also clips the top voltage at 1.4 V below input.

I've considered a MOSFET but the threshold voltage seems like it would kill the low-end.

Other circuits I see online commonly show using a fractional gain to scale the input down. But I don't want to scale it, just clip.

Am I missing some easy solution?

Comment: Are you monitoring the voltage or the current of this signal?

Comment: "*I have a 10mA circuit that I would like to monitor.*" It is not clear why this is relevant.

Comment: Use diodes to drop the voltage back down, and put a resistor in series so it doesn't overload the circuit

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm monitoring the voltage.

Comment: @DKNguyen sorry if it's not. I thought it might be important but now that I think about it if I don't want to load the circuit then it could be anything.

Comment: So not a 10mA current sensing thing then. You can clamp voltages with a serires resistor and diode pointing to the to rail you want to clamp to. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/418499/how-does-diode-clamp-protection-work You may place an opamp buffer afterwards if you so choose for even higher impedance and better drive.

Comment: @DKNguyen okay, so then if I was using an opamp with diodes built in it would just be a matter of adding a series resistor to the input (thinking the + of a Voltage Follower)? Is there a limit to how high of a value I can use?

Comment: Yes you can use the internal ESD diodes if you want. The higher the R, the less heat and less loading WHILE CLAMPING but the higher RC time constant. You still need opamp bias currents at the opamp supply voltage to flow as well

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks. I'll play with some simulations and see what I can find that works. I figured I was missing something easy like 'to increase impedance add a resistor'.